# Reduce taking a long time

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning

I am delving into proving subspaces of polynomials.

The following did not finish after several minutes on v.11.3, and took 23 seconds on v.12.0:

```
Reduce[ForAll[{t, a1, b1, c1}, Exists[{a2, b2, c2}, 
        ForAll[{x}, t*(a1 + b1*x + 5*x^2 + c1*x^3) == 
        a2 + b2*x + 5*x^2 + c2*x^3]]], Reals]
```

OTOH, all of the following *slight* variations finished in less than a second (producing `False`):

```
Reduce[ForAll[{t, a1, b1, c1}, Exists[{a2, b2, c2}, 
        ForAll[{x}, t*(a1 + 5*x + b1*x^2 + c1*x^3) == 
        a2 + 5*x + b2*x^2 + c2*x^3]]], Reals]
Reduce[ForAll[{t, a1, b1}, Exists[{a2, b2}, 
        ForAll[{x}, t*(a1 + b1*x + 5*x^2) ==
        a2 + b2*x + 5*x^2]]], Reals]
Reduce[ForAll[{t, a1, c1}, Exists[{a2, c2}, 
        ForAll[{x}, t*(a1 + 5*x^2 + c1*x^3) == 
        a2 + 5*x^2 + c2*x^3]]], Reals]
Reduce[ForAll[{t, b1, c1}, Exists[{b2, c2}, 
        ForAll[{x}, t*(b1*x + 5*x^2 + c1*x^3) == 
        b2*x + 5*x^2 + c2*x^3]]], Reals]
```

Is this a *Mathematica* issue, or a mathematics one? If the former, any workarounds, to assist speeding up the calculations?

adTHANXvance.

Comment: I don't know much about the [internals](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ComplexPolynomialSystems.html), but even the order of variables can greatly affect the computation time. It's hard to decide beforehand for which variables to solve first (imagine solving a system of equations with pen and paper), so Mathematica sticks to user provided order. On my machine, ...ForAll[{a1, b1, c1, t}... takes 8 seconds to compute, and ...ForAll[{a1,t,b1,c1}... takes 3 seconds. As for workarounds, Resolve is usually faster than Reduce.

Comment: Thank you for these insights -- although my head still spins, and I am still without an algorithm for a standardized workaround.